# Mouse over issue with IE browser windows 8.1

Tags: java, python, mysql, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my code:

```
<div id="banner_h1" class="ui-corner-tr">
TestET Department of Transportation
<a id="js_h2_agency_select_link" class="agencyselectlink" href="javascript:void(0);" title="View List of Agencies">
<img height="12" width="12" alt="Black Down Arrow" src="/images/down.gif">
</a>
<div id="js_h2_agency_select_dropdown" class="h2_agency_select_dropdown ui-corner-bottom invisible" style="position: absolute; top: 22px; left: 6px;">
<div class="dropdown_content ui-corner-all">
<a href="/site/home?action=Go&agencyid=TEST&change=changeagency" title="Lettings for Test Department of Transportation">Test Department of Transportation</a>
<a href="/site/home?action=Go&agencyid=LOCALTEST&change=changeagency" title="Lettings for Locality with Test Department of Transportation">Locality with Test Department of Transportation</a>
<a href="/site/home?action=Go&agencyid=TESTET&change=changeagency" title="Lettings for TestET Department of Transportation">TestET Department of Transportation</a>
<a href="/site/home?action=Go&agencyid=TESTCT&change=changeagency" title="Lettings for TestCT Department of Transportation">TestCT Department of Transportation</a>
<a href="/site/home?action=Go&agencyid=TESTMT&change=changeagency" title="Lettings for TestMT Department of Transportation">TestMT Department of Transportation</a>
```

This is the mouse over issue with IE,I have an mouse over element and then it opens a drop down i will click on one one of the link.

Its working fine in windows 7 all IE browser versions ,but fails in windows 8 and 8.1 with IE browser.

> Error:ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element

(Used javascript to make element visible but failed)

Here are the xpath for mouse over element

```
//div[@id='banner_h1']/a[@id='js_h2_agency_select_link']/img
```

OR
`//html/body/div/div/div[2]/a/img`   (Used Both)

Xpath after mouse over Click on the link

```
//html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/a[3]
```

Kindly please suggest me what the problem could be am unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You tried hover on link ? (this is C# exemple)

```
                //Hover on link.
                Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                IWebElement menuHoverLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='banner_h1']"));
                actions.MoveToElement(menuHoverLink);
                actions.Build().Perform();
```

after that you can click on the button you want.